# How to prove that this series of functions is uniformly convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of functions on $[a, b]$ such that:
$f_n(x) \le 0$ if $n$ is even, $f_n(x) \ge 0$ if $n$ is odd;
$|f_n(x)| \geq |f_{n+1}(x)|$ for all $x$;
$f_n$ converges to $0$ uniformly.

I have to prove that the summation of $f_n$ is uniformly convergent.

How do I approach this problem? Where should I start?

Comment: Do you know about the Ratio Test for alternating series? You can use it here.

Comment: @IshraaqParvez Oh yess, I do I think. Also I'm really sorry but could you please walk me through it a little?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type set, for future reference.

Comment: Try to apply the idea of the proof of the alternating series test to this problem. Study the proof of alternating series test first and make sure you understand it.

Comment: @Applesauce44 Yeah sure. Just expoit the fact that by the ratio test, the nth term tends to zero, and hence the sum of the series is NOT divergent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ishraaq Parvez gave you the answer but I'm going to detail.
First the theorem about Alternating Series :

Hypothetis :

- $(u_n)$ is alternate, which means either $((-1)^n u_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ or $((-1)^{n+1} u_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is positive
- $(|u_n|)$ is decreasing
- $|u_n|\rightarrow 0$ when $n\rightarrow +\infty$

Result :

- $\sum u_n$ converges
- if we note $R_n = \sum\limits_{i=n+1}{+\infty} u_i$, then for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $|R_n|\leqslant |u_n|$

Then for your problem : it is clear that for all $x$, $(f_n(x))$ is alternate.
We also know that $\sum f_n$ uniformly convergent is equivalent to $R_n = \sum\limits^{+\infty}_{i=n+1} f_i $ uniformly converges to $0$.
By the theorem on alternate series, we have first that $\sum f_n$ exists, and also that for all $x$, $|R_n|\leqslant |f_n(x)|$. So we have that $\sup |R_n| \leqslant \sup |f_n|$. (you will have remarked that the sup are defined since we have convergence)

Since $(f_n)$ uniformly converges to $0$, $\sup |f_n| \rightarrow 0$.
So $\sup |R_n| \rightarrow 0$.
Thus $\sum f_n$ uniformly converges.